# Google maps initialization pushes an empty route in the browser history stack in safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, browser

On mounting a component I am initializing google maps with some lat-long. The problem that I am facing is when I initialize the google maps with new google.map it pushed an empty route in the browser history stack. This is happening only in safari, in chrome is works fine.

Update:
I have a react component class which on mount initializes another classs which is just a wrapper around google map.

Below is the method which gets called whenever I initialize the google map class with the lat/long provided.

Everything works fine in chrome but in safari, in history stack, I see a new route save as current route, because of this I have to hit back twice to go back.

```
private initMap = () => {
  this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer, {
    center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
    clickableIcons: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    maxZoom: 15,
    styles: MAP_STYLE,
    zoom: 15,
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and clarify further what the issue is? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: done, please have a look and let me know

Comment: Thank you, but sorry I meant your full code + libraries you're using so that we can reproduce this issue from our side (although I'm already trying to with the little code snippet you've shared).